# Value of text field in protractor- undefined

Tags: protractor

I am not able to get value of label (as value is not editable and return by API).
I am using `getText`, but out put is always `undefined`. The value of this field is 2222.
using below

```js
var activatedid = element(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/mat-toolbar/div[3]/div[3]"));
activatedid.getText()
           .then(function(text) {
               console.log(this.text);
```

Comment: The content provided in your post is hardly sufficient to understand the root cause of your problem. Please edit your question and provide an [MCVE]. For more information, please see [Ask] and take the [Tour].

Comment: @surinder can you edit the question by appending the html ?

Comment: first make sure that the field is being displayed using isPresent() - .
activatedid.isPresent().then(function(text) {
               console.log(text);//Will display true or false
});
If it is present then check if you dont need to actually get the attribute value instead of text: 
activatedid.getAttribute('value').then(function(value){
console.log('field value is '+value)
})

Comment: Yeah once you have more details it'll be easier to assume, otherwise here are three shots in the dark: 1) AND THIS IS VERY LIKELY THE CASE - remove `this.` before text; 2) wrong locator, at least it doesn't seem to be reliable 3) getText() gets only visible text, thus your element could be somewhere down the page

Comment: Actually my (1)^ is your problem for sure, or one of them

Answer (score 0):

Remove `this.` before `text`, so you have

```
var activatedid = element(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/mat-toolbar/div[3]/div[3]"));
activatedid.getText()
           .then(function(text) {
               console.log(text);
           })
```